# inserting data from another project table in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I've created two table , "conversion_log_" on project1 and "test_table" on project2 in Google bigQuery.
I have been trying to select and insert data from conversion_log_ to test_table . I want to transfer orderid(STRING) of conversion_log_ whose pgid and luid matches pgid and luid in test_table but I got this error "Unrecognized name: hitobito_test at [6:10]" . I'm sure my tablename is correct.
I can't get the cause of this error . Could anyone tell me ??
sorry I'm beginner at BigQuery so if I oversight something , Please let me know .

```
insert into hitobito_test.test_table(orderid) 
select orderid 
from 
`kuzen-198289.conversion_log.conversion_log_` as p
where 
p.pgid = hitobito_test.test_table.pgid
AND
p.luid = hitobito_test.test_table.luid
```

```
test_table

pgid | luid | cv_date | orderid
4587 | U2300 | null | null
4444 | U7777 | null | null
```

```
conversion_log_

pgid | luid | cv_date | orderid | 
3232 | U5454 | 2020-08-01 | xcdf23
9786 | U3745 | 2020-08-02 | fgtd43
4587 | U2300 | 2020-08-02 | aaav3 ⬅︎ I need to send this orderid to the first line in test_table
```

If I add prijectname like below , I got this message
"Syntax error: Expected end of input but got identifier "hitobito_test" at [6:33]"

```
insert into galvanic-ripsaw-281806.hitobito_test.test_table(orderid) 
select orderid 
from 
`kuzen-198289.conversion_log.conversion_log_` as p
where 
p.pgid = galvanic-ripsaw-281806.hitobito_test.test_table.pgid
AND
p.luid = hitobito_test.test_table.luid
`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
INSERT INTO `galvanic-ripsaw-281806.hitobito_test.test_table`(orderid)
SELECT
  orderid
FROM
  `kuzen-198289.conversion_log.conversion_log_` AS p
WHERE
  EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM
    `galvanic-ripsaw-281806.hitobito_test.test_table` h
  WHERE
    p.pgid = h.pgid AND p.luid = h.luid)
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Your code did work ! but the data comes to test_table with new row like below. Is this the problem of BigQuery ?? 
     pgid | luid | cv_date | orderid
1   4587 | U2300 | null | null   ⬅︎ should be here 
2   null    |  null     |  null | 200781224

Comment: Can you please provide the output you are expecting ?

Comment: @SoumendraMishra . . . This answers the question that you asked here.  If you want values inserted into the table, you need to include them in the `insert`.

Comment: @SoumendraMishra

Comment: my expectation is the orderid is inserted into the same record of pgid 4587 but the result made new record whose pgid , luid , cv_date are null right under the above record  and  the orderid is stored in there .

Comment: You can use update statement: `UPDATE ``galvanic-ripsaw-281806.hitobito_test.test_table`` t SET orderid = (SELECT orderid FROM ``kuzen-198289.conversion_log.conversion_log_`` AS c WHERE t.pgid = c.pgid AND t.luid = c.luid) WHERE true`

Comment: @KentoTamura, additional back-tick used only to maintain comment formatting. Please ignore !

Comment: Thank you so much !!! I succeeded in inserting the orderid into the same record of pgid 4587 .

Comment: @ Soumendra Mishra